# Is there php built in array function to change value as key

Tags: php, arrays

Given an array:

```php
$array = ['active', 'pending', 'nonactive'];
```

expected manipulation result:

```php
$result = [
  'active'=>'active',
  'pending'=>'pending',
  'nonactive'=>'nonactive'
];
```

We know we can do it by itarate over array `$array`,

but is there php builtin function to get that result?

Comment: Use `array_combine` with the same array as both arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_combine` will achieve this. Pass the values as both params.

```php
$result = array_combine($array, $array);

// Expected Result
Array
(
    [active] => active
    [pending] => pending
    [nonactive] => nonactive
)
```